# variable in for loop does not give proper output in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

sh version : 1.14.7

```
#!/bin/sh
cpu_to_eth1=10
cpu_to_eth2=20
cpu_to_eth3=30
cpu_to_eth4=40
i=0
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
 echo "value of the $i th varible is $cpu_to_eth$i"
done
```

it is not working properly,the output should be

```
value of the 1 th varible is 10
value of the 2 th varible is 20
value of the 3 th varible is 30
value of the 4 th varible is 40
```

Comment: that's `$cpu_to_eth`, followed by `$i`. just as you would expect.

Comment: What are you using that you are stuck on a 20+ year old version of `bash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without requiring `bash`**:

```
#!/bin/sh
cpu_to_eth1=10
cpu_to_eth2=20
cpu_to_eth3=30
cpu_to_eth4=40
for i in 1 2 3 4; do
  eval echo "value of the $i th varible is "$"cpu_to_eth$i"
done
```

This should work in any POSIX shell (e.g. in `dash`, the default shell in Ubuntu).

The point is that you need two evaluations (for an indirect evaluation):

1. evaluate `$i` to get the name of the variable (`cpu_to_eth$i`)
2. evaluate the variable `cpu_to_eth$i` to get its actual value

The second-order evaluation needs a separate `eval` (or a bash-ism)

Comment: val=eval echo ""$"cpu_to_eth$i"  i want to store the whole value in another variable, but it is not working

Comment: You didn't ask for that. `eval another_var=\$"cpu_to_eth$i"`

Answer (score 1):

With bash, it's more appropriate to use an [array](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html) here, rather than have multiple variables.

Example of an array:

```
cpu_to_eth_arr=( 10 20 30 40 )
for i in "${cpu_to_eth_arr[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Another way, using an associative array:

```
cpu_to_eth[1]=10
cpu_to_eth[2]=20
cpu_to_eth[3]=30
cpu_to_eth[4]=40

for i in "${!cpu_to_eth[@]}"
do
    echo "value of the $i th varible is ${cpu_to_eth[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: I do not have array support in my bash version

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash` you can perform the [Shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

cpu_to_eth1=10
cpu_to_eth2=20
cpu_to_eth3=30
cpu_to_eth4=40

i=0

for i in 1 2 3 4
do
 val=cpu_to_eth${i} # prepare the variable
 echo value of the $i th varible is ${!val} # expand it
done
```

Comment: test.sh: ${!val}: bad substitution

Comment: Note that I also changed the first line: from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: ya but my bash version is too old